# How to obtain row and column numbers of image in C programming

Tags: c, image, image-processing, size

I am trying to obtain the row and column numbers of the image in C programming. I want to code an image rotation code. I don't know how to get the row and column number as a variable like in Matlab :

```
[r c ~] = size(im1);
```

With the code below I read the image. So, how can I get the row and column numbers?

```
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image_write.h"

int main() {
    int width, height, bpp;

    uint8_t* rgb_image = stbi_load("split.jpg", &width, &height, &bpp, 3);

    stbi_image_free(rgb_image);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I guess `height` is the number of rows, `width` is the number of columns, and `bpp` is the number of `uint8_t` values per pixel (one `uint8_t` per channel). So the `bpp` bytes of data for the pixel at column `x` row `y` (counting from 0) would begin at `rgb_image + (bpp * ((y * width) + x)`.

Comment: But when i want to use heigth and width like this: **Xmidpoint = heigth/2; Ymidpoint = width/2;** I am getting error "heigth" undeclared.

Comment: heigth or height?

Comment: :D You are right. No problem for now.